# Display cut off top of the screen

Tags: windows, display

I am having a problem with my monitor where the Windows desktop has shifted down by 1cm, leaving a black area at the top and the Windows task bar cut off at the bottom.

I've tried changing resolutions, checking display frequency and resetting monitor drivers and my 8800GTX drivers. I have also switched between DVI connectors at the back to no avail.

To check that the monitor itself is not faulty, I hooked it up to my laptop as a secondary display and it rendered the desktop perfectly with no black space at the top. I have also played around with the vertical alignment settings on the monitor menu but again this does not solve it.

I'd be grateful of any advice on resolving this problem, as it's driving me nuts!!!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Most LCD monitors have an auto-adjust button which will attempt to realign the image with the monitor correctly. Have you tried using this?

Comment: Yes! Several times.

Comment: You said you tried with different DVI connectors... what about with a different connection type? Does VGA work?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem - it's not a software problem, it's a hardware issue.

I fixed mine by lightly tapping the back of the screen (this is serious); it worked for a few other people as well. Check out the following site: http://forums.cnet.com/7723-19681_102-401456.html

Answer (score 0):

This might happen when you are not using the monitor's native resolution.

Another possibility is that this is a botched toolbar.
Can you right-click on it ?

Comment: I am using the monitors native resolution of 1680 x 1050 and has been fine for the past 2 years - nothing comes to mind of what's changed recently. Yes can use the toolbar just fine - this windows build is about 2 months old and not had problems before.

Comment: What I meant is if that black band is clickable, meaning that it is a Windows problem, rather than hardware.

Comment: Ah right. No it is not clickable - the mouse cannot move into that area.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have access to a machine with NVidia Control panel, but I know it has loads of options to customize the layout. Is there an option to reset back to defaults?

Also, can you check if there is any difference between your computer and laptop's display settings. (eg refresh rate, screen resolution, color-depth, etc

Answer (score 0):

check your monitor's settings. it won't be the computer's fault or anythin. it's just the settings of the monitor. check for size ad position. play around with the H and V ones. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Just restore the monitor to its "factory settings". It should be fine.